# Can rack_attack safelist a dynamically-created list of IPs (such as IPs recently used by admins)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rackattack

The rack_attack gem offers easy safelisting of a *static* list of IPs for example:

```
  # config/rack_attack.rb
  ok_ips="1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3"

  Rack::Attack.safelist('safelist these IPs') do |req|
    ok_ips.include?(req.ip)
  end
```

But is there any way to *dynamically* update a list of safelisted IPs *without* requiring a server restart to take effect?

For example, if the safelisted IPs are in Memcache under the key "OK_IPS", whatever IPs are in Memcache as of the last server restart *will* be safelisted, but any newly-added IPs will not be safelisted until the next server restart.

```
  # config/rack_attack.rb
  ok_ips = my_cache_read_method("OK_IPS") # "1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3 etc etc"

  Rack::Attack.safelist('safelist these IPs') do |req|
    ok_ips.include?(req.ip)  # IPs added after server restart wont be included yet
  end
```

Comment: The only thing I can find in the readme is that the Throttle, allow2ban and fail2ban state is stored in a configurable cache. Maybe try setting `Rack::Attack.cache.store = nil` or use duck typing to create a cache that never caches if that causes errors?

Comment: One other thing - if you load the definition of the whitelist into the the block itself is it not evaluated per request?  `Rack::Attack.safelist('safelist these IPs') do |req|;  ok_ips = my_cache_read_method("OK_IPS"); end`

Comment: great idea, max. i will try fetching it inside the request. and will post back here.

Comment: bingo. thanks. if you feel like making that an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently if you move the method into the block it will be evaluated per request instead:

```
Rack::Attack.safelist('safelist these IPs') do |req|
  ok_ips = my_cache_read_method("OK_IPS") # "1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3 etc etc"
  ok_ips.include?(req.ip)  # IPs added after server restart wont be included yet
end
```

Comment: yes, and since i'm using Memcache as cache, there's no meaningful impact on per-request performance